# html2canvas with Angular [Error parsing CSS component value, unexpected EOF html2canvas]

Tags: angular, typescript, html2canvas

I am trying to generate and export a PDF from HTML with Angular. i am using `jspdf` and `html2canvas`.

```
  generatePdf() {
    const data = document.querySelector('[pdfTarget]');

    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => { // line (*)
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jspdf('p', 'cm', 'a4');
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, 29.7, 21.0);
      pdf.save('Filename.pdf');
    });
  }
```

if i use `document.body` in line (*) it works fine. but when i use `querySelector` or `getElementById` i get this error `Error parsing CSS component value, unexpected EOF html2canvas`.

any idea ?

Comment: i have the same problem integrating jsPdf and html2canvas in angular 9 any solution?